# why foreign key not get setted in laravel migrations

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, migration, laravel-migrations

I made an exam-question relationship, every exam has less than 200 questions, but when I run migrations, I go to the PHPMyAdmin and I don't find the foreign key set, it's only a `bigint(20) unsigned` column and not linked to the exams table.

exam model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Question;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Exam extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        //
    ];

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

question model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Exam;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Question extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function exam(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class);
    }
}
```

exam migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateExamsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('examHash')->unique();
            //..
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exams');
    }
}
```

questions migrations

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('exam_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

**I've tried to:**

Use this

```
$table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams');
```

but

> Key column 'exam_id' doesn't exist in table

**EDIT**:
it can be caused because my engine is not InnoDB, regularly I change the engine to InnoDB to create foreign keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the constrained method when you define the foreign key in question's migration, change:

```
$table->foreignId('exam_id');
```

to:

```
$table->foreignId('exam_id')->constrained();
```

Comment: well it was there but I don't know how it's deleted, anyway I re-write it and still the same

Comment: did you rollback or reset your migrations?

Comment: yes I did, but still the same, can you check the edit

Comment: I've solved it, thank you for your effort man

Answer (score 2):

The method `foreignId` will only create an `UNSIGNED BIGINT` and not a foreign key constraint. To also create a constraint you need to call `constrained()` afterward.
Try this:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('exam_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

You can also find more information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints).

Comment: thanks for helping, but nothing changed,

Comment: I checked your edit and I saw that you run: `$table->foreign('exam_id')->references('id')->on('exams');`. This will not create a column but only a foreign key constraint. I advise you to try it like in my initial answer with `$table->foreignId('exam_id')->constrained();`. Also make sure to rollback the migration and run it again.

Comment: I'm sure I'm rolling back the migrations, but I'm not that familiar with laravel, so does this function needs more things to create the relationship, if no then the problem is in the engine.

Comment: I've solved it, thank you for your effort man

Answer (score 1):

the problem as I've mentioned in the question is in the engine. so I wrote

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

in both of question and exam tables...